# WebStorm minify css

Tags: webstorm, minify

I am using closure-compiler.jar to minify my .js files. However WebStorm doesn't give me an option for .css ? How can I minify .css files with WebStorm ?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second file watcher with 'Cascading Style Sheet' file type and set css specific parameters in the 'Arguments' field.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where do you see the `Cascading Style Sheet` option in my screenshot ?

Comment: I am using `closure-compiler.jar`. What are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

closure-compiler is for JavaScript only. For CSS you need to install a different filewatcher, such as YUICompressor via npm.